# Minecraft (Forge) keeps taking more and more memory, then crashes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

On my machine, I'm running a private modded minecraft server running Forge 10.12.1.1098 for Minecraft 1.7.2. My fiancé can play without any problems on my server, however when I'm playing I crash after about 10 minutes of play, either Minecraft says it ran out of memory or it just freezes up and stops working.

After some observation in the debug screen, I noticed that the RAM usage keeps climbing even when not doing anything. This happens in Single and Multiplayer.

My server uses the following batch file to launch:

```
java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=128m -jar ForgeServer.jar nogui
pause
```

My client uses the following JVM Arguments:

```
-Xms2048M -Xmx2560M
```

The Java version in question is Version 7 Update 55

My server is using the following mods:

```
Mod                     | Version
---------------------------------------------------
Applied Energistics 2   | Beta 17
BiblioCraft             | 1.7.1
Biomes O Plenty         | 2.0.0.840
BuildCraft              | 6.0.15
CodeChickenCore         | 1.7.2-1.0.0
Extra Utilities         | 1.1.0a
Factorization           | 0.8.77
ForgeMultipart          | 1.1.0.282
IndustrialCraft2        | 2.1.478
Iron Chest              | 6.0.26.721
JABBA                   | 1.1.3
Mantle                  | 0.2.8
FurnitureMod            | 3.2.9.2 beta build 2
Natura                  | 2.2.0a3
Not Enough Items        | 1.7.2-1.0.1
RailCraft               | 9.0.0.0
Tinker's Construct      | 1.6.0.a14
Tinker's Mechworks      | 0.2.7
ThaumCraft              | 4.1.1.14
Toxic Rain              | 1.0.3
VoxelMap                | 1.7.2-1.0
WAILA                   | 1.5.2a
Witchery                | 0.18.4
```

I tried disabling Toxic Rain and VoxelMap, because I thought they'd use the most memory. But to no avail.

Does anyone happen to know why this happens?

Unfortunately, these crashes produced no crash log.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about tech support for modded Minecraft.

Comment: @Frank Fair enough I'd say.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is tech support for modded Minecraft. We only provide tech support for vanilla Minecraft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Biomes O Plenty was the culprit. It's too unstable right now.

Answer (score 0):

try this @ECHO OFF
SET BINDIR=%~dp0
CD /D "%BINDIR%"
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -Xincgc -Xmx1G -jar  ForgeServer.jar nogui
PAUSE

Comment: how much gb you have if you can add one this is how -Xmx1G